# Uploading a file to s3 after downloading from a link

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-s3

I have a link in a request which is pointing to some **pdf /image** content type. My requirement is to upload the content in the link to the s3 server.
Do I have to download it and then uploading the file but I have to many call and limited file storage in the machine Or Is there any other way to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

You must upload the file to Amazon S3.

It is not possible to tell Amazon S3 to retrieve a file from a URL.

Comment: @Johan
case is i have a url in my DB  https://cdn.arstechnica.net/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/5718897981_10faa45ac3_b-640x624.jpg 
 and I want to upload the content of the URL  to the s3  bucket. so that do have to access this url link

Comment: You will need 'something' to download the content of that URL, then upload it to S3. As @gusto2 mentions, that 'something' could be any type of compute running anywhere, such as an AWS Lambda function, or some code running on an EC2 instance, or something running on your own computer. Think of S3 as a really big disk drive. You can store data on it, but it can't go out and grab information for you.

Answer (score 0):

> My requirement is to upload the content in the link to the s3 server.

we - you need some compute resource. S3 itself won't do that.

> Do I have to download it and then uploading the file 
> Or Is there any other way to achieve this.

The compute resource (logic) doesn't need to reside on your computer. You may use some AWS Compute resource near the S3, such as Lambda, EC2, ECS, ..  You may decide based on the predicted load or other requirements.